# Slide div content from left to right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I'm beginner in to jquery and i wonder always how do developers do like this. Can someone give me a simple example..?

http://static.livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_37928/#!/home

What i need is there is a menubar and when you click a link from it that link's content should  come to center of the screen by left and when you click another link that visible content should go to right and recently clicked link's content come to the screen as i mentioned.

Can anyone help me out...? It will be a great relieve to me.

Thank you.

I found a solution. This is the effect i'm looking. but i need this with a menubar. when someone click a link it's content should come like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/ykbgT/1/

Comment: from what i see in the link that you provided, you can also do it with css.
http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp

Comment: Follow this link friend. I want to move the content when i click a link. http://jsfiddle.net/gHYSN/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#moving').stop().animate({

    "left": '+=500' 

}, 250);
```

This will move the div to the right by 500 px in a time frame of 250ms.

Answer (score 0):

http://jquery.com/ - The framework suggested to get these to move.

http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery - A nice to consume tutorial on how jquery works and how to get to grips with selectors and what not.

Like @senthilbp said try giving the http://api.jquery.com/animate/ function a read through.

Read these through and if you have any trouble understanding them, first google the issue, and if that doesnt render an answer, come back and ask again, with a specific example you are having trouble with.

Comment: So he asks for a simple example, to work through himself, and you start banging on about how he's asking for the finished article.

Comment: @lededje This guy just wanted a simple exmaple, we all gave him one. Closed question. I do agree though.

Comment: Yes i follow those tutorials but i didn't know how to develop like in that site. I'm manged to do some hard coding but it didn't looks like to that site.

Comment: I need to move content when i click the link on this menubar.. http://jsfiddle.net/gHYSN/ Please help me out.